# Saplings as hair don't line up

Tags: particles, sapling-addon

I'm using the sapling generator to make a little forest scene using the Particle System. My issue is, with default Particle settings, the leaves don't line up with the branches.

[image]

how do I combat this?

Comment: This doesn't look like default settings. You could of course move leaves to place, but it's kind of hack. Can you show screenshot of Sapling settings window from the Toolshelf ? Note that it's shown only after tree creation.

Comment: You probably global transform active  in your particles settings under the *Properties Window > Particles > Render > Global*